# Creating FedEx Shipping Documnents using FedEx ship service WSDL

Tags: c#, fedex

I am in the process of integrating with the FedEx international Ship Service. But I am really stuck on one part. I am trying to create a certificate of origin using their test environment. I have followed the xml schema and have come up with the code below

```
private static void SetCustomInvoice(ProcessShipmentRequest request)
    {
        request.RequestedShipment.ShippingDocumentSpecification = new ShippingDocumentSpecification();
        request.RequestedShipment.ShippingDocumentSpecification.ShippingDocumentTypes = new RequestedShippingDocumentType[1] { new RequestedShippingDocumentType() };
        request.RequestedShipment.ShippingDocumentSpecification.ShippingDocumentTypes[0] = RequestedShippingDocumentType.CERTIFICATE_OF_ORIGIN;
        request.RequestedShipment.ShippingDocumentSpecification.CertificateOfOrigin = new CertificateOfOriginDetail();
        request.RequestedShipment.ShippingDocumentSpecification.CertificateOfOrigin.DocumentFormat = new ShippingDocumentFormat { StockType = ShippingDocumentStockType.STOCK_4X6, ImageType = ShippingDocumentImageType.PDF, ImageTypeSpecified = true, StockTypeSpecified = true };
        request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested = new ShipmentSpecialServicesRequested();
        request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.SpecialServiceTypes = new ShipmentSpecialServiceType[1] { new ShipmentSpecialServiceType() };
        request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.SpecialServiceTypes[0] = ShipmentSpecialServiceType.ELECTRONIC_TRADE_DOCUMENTS;

        request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.EtdDetail = new EtdDetail();
        request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.EtdDetail.RequestedDocumentCopies = new RequestedShippingDocumentType[1] { RequestedShippingDocumentType.CERTIFICATE_OF_ORIGIN };
        request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.EtdDetail.DocumentReferences = new UploadDocumentReferenceDetail[1] { new UploadDocumentReferenceDetail() };
        request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.EtdDetail.RequestedDocumentCopies[0] = RequestedShippingDocumentType.CERTIFICATE_OF_ORIGIN;

    }
```

But I keep getting an error message back from the web service stating “Invalid Stock Type”. Even though the shipmentDocumentStockType is an enum and I am using one of the values from it. I am still getting this error. Any ideas where I might be going wrong? 
Any information will be a great help. I have tried getting in touch with FedEx technical support and they were not really a great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a little late for you but just wanted to provide an answer in case someone else might be looking for it.

I was having a similar problem but instead of the Certificate of Origin it was with the Commercial Invoice. Turns out these forms need to be printed on a full 8.5 x 11 page in PDF format, so changing the StockType from STOCK_4x6 to PAPER_LETTER fixed it for me:

From:

`request.RequestedShipment.ShippingDocumentSpecification.CertificateOfOrigin.DocumentFormat = new ShippingDocumentFormat { StockType = ShippingDocumentStockType.STOCK_4X6, ImageType = ShippingDocumentImageType.PDF, ImageTypeSpecified = true, StockTypeSpecified = true };`

To:

`request.RequestedShipment.ShippingDocumentSpecification.CertificateOfOrigin.DocumentFormat = new ShippingDocumentFormat { StockType = ShippingDocumentStockType.PAPER_LETTER, ImageType = ShippingDocumentImageType.PDF, ImageTypeSpecified = true, StockTypeSpecified = true };`

Hope this helps

Comment: Still true. I tried PAPER_7X4.75 for commercial invoice and got an error